# Error while using NLTK/ How should I read paragraph using NLTK?

Tags: nlp, nltk

I am a total newbie. I have a custom text document which is a paragraph. I am trying to read it and display using NLTK.

following is my code;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader

corpus_root = ''
wordlists = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, 'evidence.txt')
wordlists.fileids()
wordlists.words('evidence.txt')
print(wordlists.words('evidence.txt'))
```

I am getting an error;

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position
>   19: invalid start byte

please help.

Comment: what is your goal? Just read the file and print its content? Or is there some NLP model you want to train?

Comment: My goal is to read the file and build bag of words...thank you for the comment though I found the answer...I had copied the text from Mac and was working on windows....there was some error regarding utf-8, i rewrote it on windows and errror was gone...thanks though